# Custom search results page in salesforce community

Tags: customer-portal, custom, customer-community, ui

I am creating the Salesforce community with custom UI.
There is search form in the header(its UI is customized) like:

```
<form action="/<community name>/search/SmartSearch" method="get">
    <input id="phSearchInput" type="text" name="str"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

The search results page is not consistent with the rest branded custom UI.
What are the suggestions how to customize search results UI, how to intercept/get these results and process them in custom way on custom UI.

Comment: Please find the link https://blogs.perficient.com/salesforce/2014/02/25/making-search-work-in-communities-part-2/

Comment: It sounds like your question is just about styling of the results page and not how the page functions, is that correct?

Comment: We need to display cases of only specific record types when user does a search  in communities. Is there a way to customize out of the box search functionality.